# Bevel modifier artefact on a single vertex

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups, bevel

I made a simple object and applied a single bevel modifier on a vertex group. The modifier works fine except for a single vertex (see picture below) where it created a strange  artefact.

To avoid that I tried:

- removing doubles
- recalculating normals
- checking for double faces
- recreating the group
- reopening blend file

Here is my blend file:
[image]

Has anyone an idea what is wrong with the object?

[image: bevel modifier problem on a vertex]

Comment: Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method would involve getting rid of the unnecessary vertices in the mesh to simplify it by sliding the loops towards the edges.

[image: simplifying the mesh]

The result of this is a much cleaner mesh while still retaining quad-only topology.

[image: look Mom, no tris or n-gons!]

The final result can then still be tweaked by vertex groups or bevel weights.

[image: result]

[image]

Comment: Cool, I already solved it by bevel weights, but this is even better. So I am accepting this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think there’s nothing bad with your topology, EXCEPT that it can’t fill your needs, meaning it can’t properly bevel with the *Bevel* modifier:

- You've created a vertex group to designate all the edges that are supposed to be bevelled by your *Bevel* modifier. At the top of your mesh you've selected all the border vertices because you want all the border edges to be bevelled.

[image]

- The problem is that vertex groups don't include only the vertices, it also include all the edges between vertices. Therefore your modifier will also affect all these edges:

[image]

- You can verify it, if you select all the vertex group, you'll see these edges included:

[image]

- So, as you're using a *Bevel* modifier with *Vertex Group* method it will also bevel all these edges and it will give a mess of intertwining edges. Yes by chance it kind of works better on the right side but I don't think it's satisfying either:

[image]

- If you create additional topology to make sure that the inner edges are not affected by the bevel, in my opinion it still won't work properly and it will make you loose the roundness you want:

[image]
[image]

- So I may be wrong (edit: actually it looks like the topology proposed by Metaphor_set works with modifier) for the result you wanted) but the solution is probably to do it manually and to bring some manual corrections at the end with some join vertices and dissolve edges. The *Bevel* modifier can't always do everything properly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This looks like a bevel modifier bug to me. I also managed to move the artefact to another vertex by recreating the group in a different order but I wasn't able to get rid of it. Both solutions you suggested are fine but not ideal. Because when adding topology (As you mentioned) i am missing roundness and when beveling manualy I am adding permanent geometry which I tried to avoid by the modifier because it is harder to modify the mesh later on.

Comment: yes I understood that you're trying to make non-destructive bevels but I don't think it's possible here, it's not always possible unfortunately, when you have a lot of edge loops intertwining, it doesn't always know what's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an acceptable solution for me. I wasn't able to make beveling be vertex groups working so I tried to bevel by weight. The result is not perfect (there is also a small artefact) but good enough.

[image]

[image]

The final blend file: [image]